# TableSorter - Select sort with colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I'm using the tablesorter plugin for sorting tables.

**Info**

- I have one th that spans over two different td. I still need to sort as if the th was two th:s.
- The "Testing2" is not working as expected. It should sort the third column.

**jsfiddle**

I have made an update of another persons jsfiddle. There for I did not paste his whole code directly in here.

**Jquery**

```
$('table').tablesorter();
$('select').change(function(){
    var column = parseInt($(this).val(), 10),
        direction = 1, // 0 = descending, 1 = ascending
        sort = [[ column, direction ]];
    if (column >= 0) {
        $('table').trigger("sorton", [sort]);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yke6M/53/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to add a hidden row that doesn't have a `colspan` ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/Yke6M/54/)):

```
<table class="tablesorter">
     <thead>
         <tr>
             <th>Alphabetic</th>
             <th colspan="2" style="text-align: center;">Testing</th>
             <th>Animals</th>
         </tr>
         <tr class="hidden">
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
             <td></td>
         </tr> 
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then modify your dropdown list accordingly

```
<select>
    <option value="-">Choose a column</option>
    <option value="0">Alphabetic</option>
    <option value="1">Testing</option>
    <option value="2">Testing2</option>
    <option value="3">Animals</option>
</select>
```

I'm not sure why I had such a hard time hiding that row in jsFiddle, but I ended up modifying the css to this:

```
th, tbody td {
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
}
tr.hiddden {
    display: none;
}
```